# How come I have low voltage on outlet?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have been changing all my switches and receptacle with wifi or at least a more modern one.

but there is one of them that I'm not sure why doesn't power up my lamp. I go check and the voltage seems low. not but 17v-20??

not sure if is a false reading from my meter.
How would you troubleshoot this?

Comment: Plug in and turn on a lamp and then check the voltage (use the other outlet if it's a duplex, unswitched). If it goes to zero, it was a false reading. If it stays 17-20 volts, that's the real reading. Also compare voltage readings between hot and ground - if that's ~120 volts, your neutral is probably bad, otherwise the hot is probably bad.

Comment: I've seen this once, turned out breaker needed to be turned off and on, it was one of those coupled breakers and half of it was in semi-tripped state or something.

Comment: interestingly, I tried the breaker and yes, it did work temporarily. I did get 109-120 v again. but now the problem is that as soon I plug in something the outlet stops working. whats weird is that i also have another light on the same breaker and it works. im so confused